# Android app using databases: how to manage data from user and app owner

Tags: android, database

I created an app that collects data from users (location based on google). I need to use the data to create best routes that are of interest to the app developer not the user. Do I need 2 different apps? What is the general approach in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No.
Give users access
Step 1: Decide whether your user needs global or per-app access
Before you set up permissions, you need to decide if your user needs global or per-app access.

Global: Global access applies to all apps in your developer account.
Per-app: Per-app access only applies to the selected app.
For details on how global and per-app access impacts a specific permission, select the permission below under "Permission definition & uses."

Step 2: Add users & turn permissions on or off
If you're an account owner or admin, you can add users to your Play Console account and manage permissions across all apps or for specific apps.

Sign in to your Play Console.
Click Settings Settings > Users & permissions.
To add a user, select Invite new user and follow the onscreen instructions.
To update permissions for an existing user, hover over their email address and select the pencil icon Pencil icon / edit icon.
Use the "Role" selector to choose a pre-defined role or use the checkboxes for individual permissions.
Choose whether each permission applies to all apps in your developer account ("Global") or specific apps.
To add an app to the permissions table, use the down arrow next to "Add an app."
To see details for each permission, review the permission definitions section.
Click Send Invitation.
Note: If you don't choose an access expiration date, the user has ongoing access to the Play Console account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is still not clear to me how to proceed. I have one app. How to grant different access rights to a user and to a developer? Your reply is for permissions for the whole app. I am trying to have one app with 2 sets of permissions. Once the app is downloaded, how does the app know that the user is a regular user and not a developer? How to separate activities within the app so they are only visible to either the user or the developer? There are user activities and developer activities in the same app. How can I restrict access to them based on the user type?